# Unable to Upload a Plugin into Fortify

Tags: fortify

When i am trying to upload the sample-parser plugin i am getting the error "***Error loading/validating plugin metadata fro jar***". Below is the Image of it.

[image]

Below lines are from the log file.

```
2019-03-05 02:25:19,719 | INFO  | 95-6077bc1af140] | ExchangeProcessorRequest         | 9 - com.fortify.plugin.camel - 1.3.1071 |  Plugin com.fortify.plugin.runtime.manager received message com.fortify.plugin.messaging.manager.PluginInstallRequest@45feadce; session null
2019-03-05 02:25:19,723 | INFO  | pool-20-thread-1 | PluginManagerImpl                | 19 - com.fortify.plugin.runtime - 1.3.1071 |  INSTALLING plugin from remote URL [file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Fortify_SSC_Server_18.10/apache-tomcat-8.5.28/temp/SSC-ssc/576e452a660d48659b21388ef203262b.jar]
2019-03-05 02:25:19,751 | INFO  | pool-20-thread-1 | PluginManagerImpl                | 19 - com.fortify.plugin.runtime - 1.3.1071 |  Location for bundle to be installed: [ffinstall:/C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Fortify_SSC_Server_18.10/apache-tomcat-8.5.28/temp/576e452a660d48659b21388ef203262b.jar_23660754815308672.jar]
2019-03-05 02:25:19,755 | WARN  | pool-20-thread-1 | PluginManagerImpl                | 19 - com.fortify.plugin.runtime - 1.3.1071 |  Plugin installation FAILED.
2019-03-05 02:25:19,755 | ERROR | pool-20-thread-1 | PluginManagerMessageHandler      | 9 - com.fortify.plugin.camel - 1.3.1071 |  Failed to install plugin from URL=file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Fortify_SSC_Server_18.10/apache-tomcat-8.5.28/temp/SSC-ssc/576e452a660d48659b21388ef203262b.jar
com.fortify.plugin.runtime.metadata.PluginMetadataException: Error loading/validating plugin metadata from jar
    at com.fortify.plugin.runtime.metadata.internal.PluginMetadataLoaderImpl.loadPluginJarMetadata(PluginMetadataLoaderImpl.java:46)
    at com.fortify.plugin.runtime.transformer.AbstractPluginUrlHandler.doTransform(AbstractPluginUrlHandler.java:109)
    at com.fortify.plugin.runtime.transformer.AbstractPluginUrlHandler.access$000(AbstractPluginUrlHandler.java:40)
    at com.fortify.plugin.runtime.transformer.AbstractPluginUrlHandler$Connection.getInputStream(AbstractPluginUrlHandler.java:85)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)[:1.8.0_181]
    at com.fortify.plugin.runtime.manager.internal.PluginManagerImpl.installPluginJar(PluginManagerImpl.java:266)
    at com.fortify.plugin.runtime.manager.internal.PluginManagerImpl.installRemotePluginJar(PluginManagerImpl.java:246)
    at com.fortify.plugin.runtime.manager.internal.PluginManagerImpl.installPlugin(PluginManagerImpl.java:116)
    at com.fortify.plugin.camel.manager.PluginManagerMessageHandler.handleInOutRequest(PluginManagerMessageHandler.java:49)[9:com.fortify.plugin.camel:1.3.1071]
    at com.fortify.plugin.camel.manager.PluginManagerMessageHandler.handleInOutRequest(PluginManagerMessageHandler.java:39)[9:com.fortify.plugin.camel:1.3.1071]
    at com.fortify.plugin.camel.helpers.ExchangeProcessorRequest.handle(ExchangeProcessorRequest.java:37)[9:com.fortify.plugin.camel:1.3.1071]
    at com.fortify.plugin.camel.helpers.ExchangeProcessor$AsyncTask.run(ExchangeProcessor.java:123)[9:com.fortify.plugin.camel:1.3.1071]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_181]
```

I have copied the metadata information (.xml file ) in the same directory as the .JAR file.

Can someone tell me, if i am missing something here? Or i have to do it in a different way ??

Below is the link for sample parser.

https://github.com/fortify/sample-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved.

I am using wrong .java files to convert as a .JAR files.

I got success when i have used the correct .java files along with .xml file.